# Is there a way in Lua to list a directory without using io.popen?

Tags: lua, popen, ls

I'm trying to list the files of a directory without using the systems shell like it is done by using io.popen or os.execute.

So, the following does not work:

```lua
local content = io.popen("ls -la", "r")
```

Background: the interpreter is stripped down and does not support the above mentioned functions in the standard libraries.

Is there any other **small and simple** way to perform a directory listing in Lua?

Comment: [LuaFileSystem](https://keplerproject.github.io/luafilesystem/)

Comment: Does your interpreter support `require` or `dofile`?

Comment: No, require and dofile are also not possible. Will have a look at LuaFileSystem. Hopefully it is very small and fits into the limited RAM of my embedded system.